# Выставить префиксы в css

Tags: html, css

Можно ли в уже написанном сайте как то автоматически выставить префиксы для всех нужных свойств в css? Можно ссылочку. Спасибо!

Comment: что значит "префиксы для всех нужных свойств"? сформулируйте точнее.

Comment: Не знаю что вы не поняли, но вот ниже мне дали вполне исчерпывающий ответ.

Comment: Тем лучше. В этом и есть сила Сообщества: где один не поймет, другой даст исчерпывающий ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть онлайн сервис для автоматического добавления префиксов: [**ЖМИ**](https://autoprefixer.github.io/ru/)

Ну а самый лучший вариант использовать [`autoprefixer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-autoprefixer) в сборщике `gulp`, но для этого вы должны быть знакомы с [`node.js`](https://nodejs.org/en/).

ps. [**Мануал**](http://andy-carter.com/blog/a-beginners-guide-to-the-task-runner-gulp) по работе с `gulp` для самых маленьких.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vW51JUVT66w   вот на русском